Clicking on a folder on my desktop opens two Nautilus windows, the one I selected and the Desktop itself. How do I stop this?
I have seven folders on my Desktop, one for each of my active projects. When I attempt to open any of them, two Nautilus windows open: the one I clicked on (home/me/Desktop/Project1), and another with the Desktop itself (home/me/Desktop). This has been happening for the past couple of months, I think. This is happening on Ubuntu 24.04. How can I fix this?

Please edit the question and add the version of Ubuntu you are using.
